# read file using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to read and parse a text file using JQuery and the code I'm using seems to error out.

```
//Attempt 6
alert("Test Alert 9"); //js file does load into index.html
$.get( "exchanges.txt",
    function( data ) {
        //idk what the following two lines do, I got them from:
        //http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert("check it");
    })
    //should execute if works?
    .done(function() {
        alert( "second success" );
    })
    //should execute if any error
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
        alert( "finished" );
    });
```

The following alerts print:

1. "Test Alert 9"
2. "error"
3. "finished"

My question:
Is there a way to check *what* the error is?
And/or does anyone know what the error might be?

Edit: for clarification, the exchanges.txt file is located in the same folder as the js file

Edit: Updated to throw error to console. Error prints:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load      file:///C:/Users/Invictus/Documents/GitHub/BTCExchangesMaterialize/exchanges.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Fixed this error by moving the exchanges.txt to the main folder instead of the js/ folder.

New error:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
file:///C:/Users/Invictus/Documents/GitHub/BTCExchangesMaterialize/exchanges.txt.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.sendjquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 n.extend.ajaxjquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 n.each.n.(anonymous function)exchangesParser.js:3 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: check your browser's network tab(developer tools) to see what is the repose.. also the fail handler has a status param

Comment: where is **exchanges.txt** ?

Comment: the exchanges.txt file is located in the same folder as the js file

Comment: `.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
    console.log(xhr, status, error)
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.get` is a shorcut for $.ajax with some settings pre-enabled.
Signature of $.get is:

`$.get([String] url, [Object|String] urlparams, [Closure] callback);`

> `callback` is excecuted AFTER AJAX QUERY HAD SUCCESS.

If you plan to use jQuery promises way, you omit the success callback, and use its promises methods, `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()`

**Success Callback Way**

```
$.get( "exchanges.txt", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
    alert("checked it");
});
```

**Promises Way**

```
$.get( "exchanges.txt")
.done(function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );
    alert("checked it");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

As can be seen, promises way its more specific on handlers, since you can call a function an more points that get, this is because `$.get` (as I mentioned before) is a shorcut for `$.ajax`. Take a look of `$.get` call expanded to `$.ajax`:

**$.ajax Way**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "exchances.txt",
    success: function(data){
        $(".result").html(data);
        alert("checked it");
    },
    error: function(response){
        alert("error");
    },
    complete: function(response){
        alert("done");
    },
});
```

Just keep in mind that AJAX Request CAN NOT BE DONE to local files when referencing it with `file://` you should access them through http (apache, node), ftp or whatever other protocol u want, but never under `file://`

Read more:

[jQuery promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)
[jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ah, is there a way to access a file using both file:// and http ? Or will I have  to setup and run local server to be able to use file fetching?

Comment: Since local ajax queries are prohibited due to security reasons, you better set up a local server.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. If I seem a little naive it's because this is my first web development project.

Answer (score 0):

in your `fail` function, pass the `response`. Then you can play with the response object. Inspect your browser's console(developer tools)

```
 .fail(function( response) {
        console.log("my error response is",response);
        alert( "error" );
    })
```